# Django: make a view run only once at a time (mutex/lock/semaphore)

Tags: python, django, concurrency

Is there an easy way (ideally built-in or library) to allow at most 1 thread/process at time within a Django view? A kind of semaphore I guess. Ideally, I can make other threads return a response if the process is already running./

It doesn't need to handle any distributed system so locally managed is fine for my use case.

Using Django 1.11

Answer (score 0):

*I may be missing your meaning of what you mean by "most 1 thread/process at time within a Django view"*

The simplest way -- that I DO NOT suggest it -- is to run:
`./manage.py runserver --nothreading`

Now, that is locking it down to a single python process -to- single request at a time, not per view.. but per request.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-runserver-nothreading

Answer (score -1):

you can probably just use a file or something

something like

```
def my_view(request):
    if os.path.exists("/some/file.txt"):
       return HTTPResponse(open("/some/file.txt","rb").read())
    try:
       open("/some/file.txt","wb") as f:
          f.write("Actively running this already1")
       return render_template(my_template,...)
    finally:
       os.remove("/some/file.txt")
```